# rubymine generate routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rubymine

I am new to Ruby on Rails and have some problems.

For the development I use RubyMine IDE, I manage to create models, controllers and views, but I have problems with the routing. By default,  `routes.rb` file contains only this method `Apis::Application.routes.draw do` with an empty body.

For example, I create a controller `TestController`, then the `index` method and in `routes.rb` I add this instruction `resources :test`. So far, it works fine. But if I add another method, let's say `method1` (and the view) I can't reach it in a browser `http://localhost:3000/test/method1`.

What else should I add in `routes.rb` file?

Is there any way to make the routing automatically from the IDE, with less editing the routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :test
```

is a resourceful route which provides a mapping between HTTP verbs and URLs to controller actions. By convention, each action also maps to particular CRUD operations in a database

you can uncomment in your routes to enable the controller action mapping.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

or use -

```
match "/test/method1" => "test#method1"
```

Detailed routes info @ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it leaves all actions wide open, it would be better to specifically enumerate the actions you want to add to the resource in it's configuration block.

Comment: agreed. would prefer mapping each resources specifically. provided as an option to get started.